# Theme Options Doesn't Work On WP Multisite

Tags: theme-development, multisite, theme-options

I'm developing Wordpress themes and I'm having an issue with Theme Options on Wordpress Multisite (WPMS). My theme works like a charm on classic Wordpress (WP) installation but when I try to use it with WPMS it returns a blank page instead of a form with theme's settings.

Here what I use to initiate the theme options page:

```
function setup_theme_admin_menus() {
    add_theme_page( "Theme Options", "Theme Options", "read", "th_op", "th_op" );
    function th_op() {
        get_template_part("content", "options");
    }
}
add_action("admin_menu", "setup_theme_admin_menus");
```

As I mentioned it works as expected on WP but it refuses to render options page on WPMS.

**Yes** I am aware of http://wpmututorials.com/known-issues/did-your-users-theme-options-and-widgets-page-disappear/ which is practically everywhere and in fact does not solve the problem in a lot of cases. As you can see I use the lowest capability ever which is **"read"**.

**Yes** I tried to use theme options as SuperAdmin, JustAdmin and any user type that is possible. Nothing helps.

Please help!

Comment: Do you have a function "th_op" or did you mean "theme_options"?

Comment: My bad! I tried to shrink the code a little bit to make it fit the page with no scroll so it will be visible here ... updated!

Comment: I'd **strongly** advise against nested functions in any PHP code, it's a particularly rank code smell

Comment: Thanx for this advise @TomJNowell I will re-nest this function.  I'm actually not really good with php. But I don't think it causes this problem ...

Comment: Imagine someone gives you a list of things to do and item number 5 is actually a small parcel containing a whole new list several feet long, what's what PHP feels like when you nest functions, and it never turns out well

Comment: @TomJNowell I was wrong nesting the functions! I'm really sorry!! ))

Comment: Not to worry, but do change your code, your `th_op` function is what the APIs expect to call, so it should be in the global namespace but it isn't. Let us know if this change fixes the problem

Comment: Also: your settings page may display, but your settings won't actually be able to *save*, if you use a capability such as `read`. Please use `edit_theme_options` instead.

Comment: I've just realized that the problem is with get_tamplate_part() function not with the multisite or whatever. For some reason it worked fine when I used it locally, but when I put it on my online servers it stopped working ... sorry everyone for bothering (((

Comment: It seems like I have a corrupted content-options.php file! Sorry for bothering once again ... how to erase my question form the history? The amount of shame on me right now is unbearable!!